# AWS Lambda: Delete S3 File After Downloaded

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda

I've got a Lambda function that writes a file to S3 and then returns a signed-url to that file. Within my angular app this value is received and immediately gone to in order to download the file from S3. After the file is downloaded I want it deleted from S3.

I know I can trigger the deletion from the Angular application, but I'd really like the deletion not to be dependent on the client so that I know it actually happens. What is the best way to handle this?

I would think that deleting the file 15-30 seconds after the URL is returned is probably really safe, but I'm not sure the best way to trigger this with Lambda.

I was thinking of using a setInterval, but that seems messy since I'm keeping Lambda running for quite a bit longer than it needs to run.

Are there any cleaner options that aren't overly complicated?

I already have an expiration on the S3 bucket, but the shortest interval you can set on that is 1 day. That is much longer than I'd like to keep the item around.

Comment: I don't think there's a good way to do that in the Lambda, e.g. it will take longer to download the file than 15-30 seconds. Why keeping a file for 1 day is not an option for you? As a workaround you can have a service that will remove files that are older than 1h for example, or you can incorporate such code in your Lambda if needed

Comment: Or you could leverage CloudTrail to detect and act on relevant GetObject API calls. Here's an example: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-cloudtrail-example.html

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin The files contents are very sensitive. The less time I hold the data, the less risk I'm under. I'll checkout the possibility of using a service to delete everything that is 1hr old. That is a good idea.

Comment: @jarmod CloudTrail looks like another good possibility, looking at that option too. Thanks!

Comment: One concern regarding cloud trail that I have is when the event is fired - when the file is downloaded, or when the request to get it is made, so it's worth checking when it happens!

Comment: Given that the files are sensitive, perhaps your download button function should actually be a quick GET to your app server to retrieve a time-limited URL followed by the download to the browser from that URL. Make the time-limited URL expire very quickly (seconds).

Comment: @jarmod Already doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do this is by using S3 events that can trigger Lambda directly after a download. If an additional delay is required, you could also make the S3 event go to an SQS queue first (with settings to delay message delivery by x time) and let the SQS queue trigger a new lambda function for the removal.